# JSON encoding a viewModel to send to server - getting 500 error when trying to decode?

Tags: json, knockout.js

I am attempting to send data from my viewModel to the server as JSON

This is my view model, I can't see why it is failing - the JSON passes on JSON test sites.

Server keeps throwing a 500 error the second I try to run json_decode - which makes me think the data isn't valid JSON - tearing my hair out!!!

Any help would be appreciated!!

```
var companyInfoViewModel = function (data) {
var self = this;

data = data || {};

self.data = ko.observable(data);
self.id = ko.observable(self.data().id || '');
self.companyName = ko.observable(self.data().companyName || '');
self.address1 = ko.observable(data.address1 || "");
self.address2 = ko.observable(data.address2 || "");
self.town = ko.observable(data.town || "");
self.postcode = ko.observable(data.postcode || "");
self.mainNumber = ko.observable(data.mainNumber || "");
self.mainFax = ko.observable(data.mainFax || "");
self.mainEmail = ko.observable(data.mainEmail || "");
self.startDate = ko.observable(data.startDate || "");
self.uniqueTaxpayersReference = ko.observable(data.uniqueTaxpayersReference || "");
self.defaultTaxRate = ko.observable(data.defaultTaxRate || "");

self.fullAddress = ko.computed(function () {
    return self.address1() + ", " + self.address2() + ", " + self.town() + ", " + self.postcode();
}, this);


save = function (){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: rootURL + "clients/client",
            data: ko.toJSON(self),
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data){console.log(data)}
                    //function(data){window.location.href = site_URL + "clients/client/id/" + data}
        });
};


}
```

Comment: console it `ko.toJSON(self)` or show the server side code

Comment: Which framework do you use on the server side? How does your server side code look like? You might also need to set the `contentType` property in your ajax request instead of the datatype so try with `contentType: "application/json",`

Comment: Is that `self.save`, or are you setting a global variable?